# Tradingview Backtesting: List of trades lists entry/exit at the open. How do I get it to show the entry/exit at different points?

Tags: pine-script

I am running backtests for my strategy on Tradingview. When I open the list of trades, I notice that all of the market **entries** and **exits** are at the **open**. This doesn't yield the results that I want.  I want to **enter** from the **previous day's high** and **exit** at the **current day's close.** Is there any way to get the list of trades to display an entry onto the previous day's high and an exit at the current day's close? I would like this to happen so I can export the list of trades onto Excel so I can gather data for more backtesting. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common misuse of backtesting, many systems have flags that define if you can do intra-bar trading, that means before a bar with Open, High, Low, Close is formed you can execute positions.

This is normally not allowed because in a reay system you don't know what is the high until the bar has closed, and after it closed you may not be able to execute at the high.